# How to make search results appear in a field under the search bar?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm making an iOS app where the search bar is in the middle of a page (Google Style, it's simple). The search bar in this case is also just a text field.

I'm trying to make it so that the search results appear right under this search bar (Google Instant style) and give suggestions while the user is typing. I tried using a SearchResultsDisplayController but it expects a TableView which I am not planning on using.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a pretty good way!

Just make a UITableView (set it to hidden) and put it under the search bar. Then, put your logic for searching in:

```
- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

And make it appear! (Set hidden property to false)

Make sure that you've implemented the protocols `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` and `UISearchBarDelegate`.

Only trouble I'm having is I can't make it stay hidden if I type into it and then delete all the text in the search bar. It disappears for a second and then comes back with random values.